# Capture onClose event for Spreadsheet App Modal Dialog in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, modal-dialog, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to do something when the Modal Dialog (opened using [`showModalDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))) is closed from the Spreadsheet App.

However I cannot find the reference of such event, in the API documents provided by Google. [I found how to capture this event in a Alert Box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet)), and by using this piece of code I can capture how the user closed the Alert Box, but I cannot use this in a Modal Dialog or a Modeless Dialog.

Is there a way to do this? Please kindly answer if you do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is **not** possible. And you should write your script in a way that this does not matter. For example, by showing a big action button in the dialog, making it clear to the user that he must click there for the script to continue.

But if you really want to make this happen, I guess you could use an [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) dialog that make regular async calls to the backend and each call waits for the next one before quitting, then if the "next" call does not get in time, it can assume the dialog got closed and execute your close procedure instead of simply quitting.

Comment: Thank you, I was desperate trying to figure out how to do this. This should really, really be something offered by GAS--at least, coming from an Android background, seems an obvious utility they are in err not to offer something like being able to pass a callback with a successhandler, for when the sidebar is closed.

Comment: Also as to the use case: the sidebar enables (in google sheets) selectively setting the background of cells matching some criteria. How am I supposed to know when to clear any of this "highlighting" if the user closes the sidebar with the GAS given close button, since you can't add an event listener to it (AFAIK).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative solution. You can use google hosted jquery in the HTML (served by GAS) to track unload events when the page is closed. Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>

  <!-- Minified google hosted jquery (see https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- And here's where the magic happens -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( e => {
      console.log('-- DOM ready --');

      /** Add jquery unload listener */
      $(window).on('unload', e => {
        console.log("Invoked just before unload");
        // do pre-unload stuff
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this without Jquery, it does not get called as expected for a sidebar. The closest thing I could get was a visibility state change, and only when navigating away from and to the page, not actually closing the sidebar.