# Google Apps Script; Sidebar OnClose

Tags: html, google-apps-script, sidebar

Is there a way to hook into the CLOSE event of the Ui Sidebar ?

I read up on the docs but could not find one.

Use-Case: User choices on the Sidebar updates the spreadsheet visually like coloring cells for easy visual responses. However, then the user abruptly closes the Sidebar - leaving the physical changes already made to the spreadsheet (such as coloring). To undo those changes, need to hook into close event of Sidebar.

Any ideas / other ways ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture onClose event for Spreadsheet App Modal Dialog in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092149/capture-onclose-event-for-spreadsheet-app-modal-dialog-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: [Try this answer from the duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45843715/6586255)